# Vectorized R function for summing above rows

Tags: r, dataframe, vectorization

I don't have the right language for looking this up in the R docs or on Google so I'm hoping someone here can help me out. Let's say I have a data frame with two columns. One column is a vector of independent observations and I want the other to be the sum of all the observations in the rows above. I know I can do that with *pply functions, for example:

```
> df <- data.frame(x=runif(5), y=0)
> df
          x y
1 0.4068298 0
2 0.9352350 0
3 0.3918638 0
4 0.2925178 0
5 0.1949071 0
> df$y <- sapply(X = 1:5, FUN = function(i) sum(df$x[1:i]))
> df
          x         y
1 0.4068298 0.4068298
2 0.9352350 1.3420647
3 0.3918638 1.7339285
4 0.2925178 2.0264462
5 0.1949071 2.2213534
```

But since I have to repeatedly do this as observations are updated I think the code will be faster, more reliable, and just plain cleaner if I use a vectorized function. Is there anything like that?

Comment: `cumsum` is the cumulative sum.

Comment: @Frank  Thanks for the comment.  I thought it would be a bit harder :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply Frank's comment:

```
df$y <- cumsum(df$x)
```